# Get Radio Value to Carry over pages with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a very simple dot chasing game as a homework assignment, and I cannot figure out how to carry over the difficulty selection from the index page to the actual game page.

**Index Page**

```
<form id="difficulty" name="difficulty" action="game.html">
  <input type="radio" name="diff" id="easyDiff" value="easy">
  <label for="easyDiff">Easy</label>
  <input type="radio" name="diff" id="medDiff" value="medium" checked="checked">
  <label for="medDiff">Medium</label>
  <input type="radio" name="diff" id="hardDiff" value="hard">
  <label for="hardDiff">Hard</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Start Game!" onClick="setDifficulty()"/>
</form>
```

**Game Page**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DotSmasher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dotSmasher.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="dotSmasher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body onLoad="setGameAreaBounds(); startGameTimer()" onResize="setGameAreaBounds()">
    <div id="scoreLabel">Score: 0</div>
    <div id="pageTitle">DotSmasher</div>
    <div id="start">
      <button id="startButton" onClick="start()">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div id="stop">
      <button id="stopButton" onClick="pause()">Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="gameArea">
      <button id="dot" onClick="detectHit()"></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code**

Variables count, timer, and difficulty are instantiated at the beginning of the page

```
var score = 0;
var aWidth;
var aHeight;
var timer;

var count = 30;
var counter = setInterval(startGameTimer, 1000);
var difficulty;

function startGameTimer(){
    count -= 1;
    if (count <= 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        alert("Game has ended, Thank you for playing on " + difficulty + "!");
        return;
    }

}

function setDifficulty(){
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("diff");
    for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
            difficulty = radioButtons[i].value;

        }
    }
}
```

For some reason i am getting an undefined error and cannot figure out what it could be.

Comment: since you are navigating from one page to another the variables created in page1 will not be available in page2... you can look at cookie/WebStorage as a solution to store the data temporarily

Comment: Arun, I know nothing about cookies, and I believe it is out of the scope of this course.  However, as an avid learner, I will pursue your option to see what results it may have.  Would following this be the right way? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your script at the top in your page and in `head` tag, try this:

```
<script>
    function setDifficulty(){
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("diff");
        for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
            if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
                difficulty = radioButtons[i].value;
                alert(difficulty);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="radio" name="diff" id="easyDiff" value="easy">
        <label for="easyDiff">Easy</label>
        <input type="radio" name="diff" id="medDiff" value="medium" checked="checked">
        <label for="medDiff">Medium</label>
        <input type="radio" name="diff" id="hardDiff" value="hard">
        <label for="hardDiff">Hard</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Start Game!" onclick="setDifficulty();"/>
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/y6QxD/)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, the variable gets stored to that page but when I move onto the game itself I get the undefined error

Comment: Sorry where is your form? In Game page have no element with name "diff"?

Comment: My form is in the index page.  From there it takes the value and passes it to the next page, game.html

Comment: You can not do that! Because javascript is only running in a single page! I mean for each page must have the single javascript for it. Now for your case, I think you should do every in the only one page by replace contents of the "div" like screen game. For example: You will have a <div id="screenGame"><!--Initial Page(just some html elements and process something)--></div>, then move Game Page <div id="screenGame"><!--Replace all with something new( this is Game page)--></div>. Sorry for my English!